# Compara objetos dentro de un arraylist

Tags: java

Tengo un arraylist de 2 cosas tornillo y tacos.
tengo que hacer un listado solo de los taocos por lo que se me ha ocurrido un metodo del estilo al to String pero dentro del for comparar los objeto pero no se como hacerlo exactamente

```
   public String listarTacos(){
    String cadena = "";
        for (Articulo a : articulos) {
        if(a.equals(Taco)==0)
        cadena += a.toString();
        }
    return cadena;
}
```

Comment: Carlos. los 2 List que mencionas, los recibe el método listarTacos como parámetros?

Comment: hay un list de 2 objetos dfiferentes tiene tacos y tornillos

Comment: tu tienes un list en la clase como objeto y quieres listar solo de ese list los objetos taco

Comment: Como sabes ques un taco o tornillo el elemento en la lista?

Comment: esa es la cosa que no se como

Comment: ¿Has probado con `instanceof`?

Comment: Gracias era eso lo que necesitaba